# Are there any vegan BDSM products?

Tags: veganism, clothing, leather

Are there any vegan alternatives to leather-based BDSM products (clothing, whips, even handcuffs have a leather covering sometimes)?

Answer (score 7):

There is at least one company that creates BDSM products without leather: [EthicalKink](http://www.ethicalkink.com/) (NSFW link).

They ship worldwide and you can return unused products for free.

P.S. I am not affiliated with the brand in any way.

Answer (score 3):

There used to be place called kinkclusive. But they are currently on a hiatus. They used to have a huge collection of vegan BDSM things. All of them were handmade! Tried to read about it after coming across this question. I found this fact very interesting so shared it.
 I also read that leather is not actually necessary for these products can be used w/o them.

P.S not associated to the above mentioned company in anyway.